# Basic RegEx pattern throws non desired results

Tags: python, regex

I have inputs like these (in a list named `mylist`):

```
Encontrados 2 Inmuebles.  Página 1 de 1
Encontrados 1 Inmuebles.  Página 1 de 1
Encontrados 0 Inmuebles.
Encontrados 1.931 Inmuebles.  Página 1 de 129
Encontrados 12 Inmuebles.  Página 1 de 1
```

I want to extract the first occurrence of each line to be a double digit number 0-99. The desired output is:

```
[' 2 ', ' 1 ', ' 0 ', ' 12 ']
```

I don't want the 4th line matches because there are more than two digits (in spanish the decimal point is the comma, and the thousands separator is the dot)

My aproach is this pattern `( \d{1,2} )`, with `mask = re.compile(' \d+ ')`
then I take the first group with `[(mask.search(item)).group(0) for item in mylist]`

But the output that I get is:

`[' 2 ', ' 1 ', ' 0 ', ' 1 ', ' 12 ']`

I believe that this happens because the first occurrence in `Encontrados 1.931 Inmuebles.  Página 1 de 129` string is the '1' that follows the 'Página' word.  But I can fix this bug on my own.

Comment: How about splitting each line by the spaces, then doing a check on the second value of the array? One way (not sure if it's the best way) to assist would also be to remove the periods (don't need them if they aren't floats) and then check for any value < 100.

Comment: @RyanO'Donnell has a point here. No real need for a regex in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Proposed solution

#### Use a negative lookahead `(?!)`

Specify that there should not be a decimal point after the digit, like so:

```
\d{1,2}(?!\.)
```

**However** this will still match the number after Página. So you may want to be even more specific:

```
( \d{1,2}(?! de |\.) )
```

This negates the word "de" from appearing after the match, as per the example.

### Online Example:

#### Regex101

http://regex101.com/r/rN0uB5

Comment: Thanks @VasiliSyrakis, the second pattern is just I looking for.  And more thank to show me that Regex101 tool, I didn't know it.

Comment: @Trimax I just want to point out that if you care about performance, lookarounds take a little bit more processing time and if they can be avoided, I'm all for avoiding them.

Comment: Indeed, Jerry is right. Lookarounds and a couple of other tokens such as `^$` are called "Zero-length assertions". The reason they can cost performance is due to the multiple possibilities that the system has to check. It is especially noticeable in long variable length expressions such as `\d{1,99}`

Comment: @Jerry, sorry by my ignorance but, what are the 'lookarounds' in  regex?

Comment: It is a token which allows you to assert that certain characters exist, without matching them. For example: `hello world` is matched by `(?<=hello )world` but only returns `world`.

Comment: @Trimax It's a whole topic in itself as you can see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but in brief, they are things in a regex that make checks and based on those checks say whether there should be a match or not. An example of a positive lookahead (one which makes sure there's something ahead) is `a(?=b)` which will match any `a`, as long as there's a `b` after it. Conversely, with a negative lookahead, `a(?!b)` will match any `a` only if there's _no_ `b` after it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you could use something like this:

```
mask = re.compile('^Encontrados (\d{1,2}) ')
```

And then use `.group(1)` to get the number alone.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/tN2xO1)

Otherwise, if you want to get strictly the first number, maybe something like this:

```
mask = re.compile('^\D* (\d{1,2}) ')
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/bA1hS2)